# Distribute persons on days

Tags: javascript, random

I have 15 persons in an array

```
names = ["A", "B", "C", ...];
```

and the dates in a month, representing Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday and Sunday

```
days = [1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 8 ..., 31];
```

I have to randomly distribute the persons at least 2 times in the month but there are some conditions.

Some of the persons have some preferences, saying which weekdays they prefer.

How can I store their preferences and how can I distribute the persons on all the days, so each day has a person?

I guess I have to loop through the days and randomly pick one of the persons, and before picking the person, I have to check if it is OK with his/her preferences.. If the person has been used two times, he/she should be deleted from the array, so he/she cannot be used again.

Is this a correct approach to the problem?

## Edit

My code so far

```
function getDaysArray(year, month) {
    var personNames = ["A", "B", "C"];
    var numDaysInMonth = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
    var daysInWeek = ['Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'];
    var daysIndex = { 'Mon': 0, 'Tue': 1, 'Wed': 2, 'Thu': 3, 'Fri': 4, 'Sat': 5, 'Sun': 6 };
    var index = daysIndex[(new Date(year, month - 1, 1)).toString().split(' ')[0]];
    var indexExceptions = [100];
    var daysArray = [];
    var personName, date, weekdayName;

    // loop through all days in month
    for (i = 0, length = numDaysInMonth[month - 1]; i < length; i++) {
        personName = personNames[Math.floor( Math.random() * personNames.length )];
        date = i + 1;
        weekdayName = daysInWeek[index++]
        daysArray.push(date + '. ' + weekdayName + ': ' + personName);

        // reset to new week
        if (index == 7) index = 0;
    }

    return daysArray;
}

console.log(getDaysArray(2015, 10));
```

Comment: Store people as objects, adding names and preferences as properties. But it seems there’s some more logic necessary (like linking the number of day in month to number of weekday). You could provide your current code in a snippet or a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/). That way, it can be helped more specific.

Comment: This is also what i recommended bellow in my answer using an array of people objects and an array of date objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By deleting them after 2 then your function will fail for the 31st day of the month with 15 people. I would use your approach with a couple additional points.

```js
var failCount=0;
var maxFail=15;

        function randomPerson(personsArray){
   return(Math.floor(Math.random() * personsArray.length));
          
        }


        function makeSchedule(personsArray, calendarArray){
          var shiftsPerPerson=Math.floor(calendarArray.length/personsArray.length);
          var extraShifts=calendarArray.length-(shiftsPerPerson*personsArray.length);
          for(i=0; i<calendarArray.length-extraShifts; i++){
               var calendarDay=calendarArray[i];
              var selectedPerson=personsArray[randomPerson(personsArray)];
              loopBreak==false;
                while(selectedPerson.availability[calendarDay.dayOfWeek]==false || selectedPerson.shifts > shiftsPerPerson-1 && loopBreak==false){
                    selectedPerson=randomPerson(personsArray);
                    if(failCount>maxFail){
      selectedPerson=failSafe(calendarDay)
      if(selectedPerson==false){
       return false;
      }else{
       loopBreak=true;
      }
     }
                    failCount++;
                }
                loopBreak=false;
                failCount=0;
                calendarDay.selectedPerson=selectedPerson;
                selectedPerson.shifts++;
            
            }
          for(i=0; i<extraShifts; i++){
            var calendarDay=calendarArray[i+calendarArray.length-extraShifts];
              var selectedPerson=personsArray[randomPerson(personsArray)];
                while(selectedPerson.availability[calendarDay.dayOfWeek]==false || selectedPerson.shifts > shiftsPerPerson){
                    selectedPerson=randomPerson(personsArray);
                }
                calendarDay.selectedPerson=selectedPerson;
                selectedPerson.shifts++;
            
            }
          
          
          
          
        }
        
        function failSafe(calendarDay){
   
   var canWork=[];
   var isPossible=false;
   for(j=0; j<personsArray.length; j++){
    person=personsArray[j];
    if(person.shifts<shiftsPerPerson && person.availability[calendarDay.dayOfWeek]==true){
     canWork.push[j];
     isPossible=true;
    }
   }
   if(isPossible){
    if(canWork.length>1){
     var selectedPerson=canWork[randomPerson(canWork)];
     return selectedPerson
     
    }else{
     selectedPerson=canWork[0];
    }
    
   }else{
     for(j=0; j<personsArray.length; j++){
    person=personsArray[j];
    if(person.shifts<shiftsPerPerson+1 && person.availability[calendarDay.dayOfWeek]==true){
     canWork.push[j];
     isPossible=true;
    }
    
    
   }
   
   if(isPossible){
    if(canWork.length>1){
     var selectedPerson=canWork[randomPerson(canWork)];
     return selectedPerson
     
    }else{
     selectedPerson=canWork[0];
    }
  }
 }
 return false;
```

Basically instead of having an array of names i have an array of people objects and array of objects for the days.

WHERE we have array of persons and person.Name=persons name
person.Availability is an array of days of week and are true or false if they can or can not work.
person.shifts is of course 0 at the beginning and is incremented with each shift given. The first loop goes through the number of days that can be evenly devided among your employees then the second loop gives 1 additional shift to a few people to fill any additional spaces needed. Each person chosen are then placed into the date object as calendarDay.selectedPerson

While your approach was a good start this will allow flexibility of adding and removing people from the array and working with any number of days of month without recoding. Hope it works, didnt test the code below so may have syntax errors in it but the concept should work!

I added the failSafe function that basically if the function fails to find an available employee a predetermined number of times it will search for all available employees then randomly assign one of them. If none is found a false will be returned from the make schedule function.

```js
  var person =  {
    Name:"Persons Name", 
    shifts:0,
    availability :[{
       Monday: true,
       Tuesday:true,
       Wednesday:true,
       Thursday:true,
       Friday:true,
       Saturday:true,
       Sunday:true
       }]};
  personsArray.push(person);

//DO THIS FOR EACH PERSON

var calendarDay= {
  Day:1,
  dayOfWeek:Monday,
  SelectedPerson=null
  };

calendarArray.push(calendarDay);
//DO THIS FOR EACH DAY OR BUILD LOOP TO DO THIS FOR YOU
```

Comment: Looks really good but I'm still unsure what the personsArray and calendarArray should look like. Can you give a very basic example?

Comment: of course. I jsut posted an edit with the declarations for the 2 arrays. They are just simply an array of objects to make it easier to work with the data. You could also use an array of arrays or 2 parallel arrays but this in my opinion is the cleanest approach so that everything has assosciative names as javascript doesnt allow ASSOC arrays

Comment: as stated above the building objects for the days and people is personal prefference if you are more familiar with another way of storing and accessing the data then use whatever method you like. The methods above can be implemented with any form of arrays or such.

Comment: @Jamgreen did this help?

Comment: It really did! Thank you. The only problem with this logic is that some people gets way more shifts than other because of randomness. It would probably be better to randomly pick an index, and then place each person (starting from the random index to the last necessary index) on the remaining shifts. This logic also favors the people with less availability, since they will be picked less often in the random process.

Comment: Jam this code above gives every person equal shifts except 1 person gets an extra shift on 31 day months. This is the purpose of the Person.shifts counter and checking that this person.shifts is less than (days in month/employees) rounded to the nearest whole number before giving a new shift to this employee.

Comment: I made 1 big mistake! the number of extra shifts integer is set incorrectly. IT should be         var extraShifts=calendarArray.length-(shiftsPerPerson*personsArray.length);

Comment: @Jamgreen the above edit should correct this problem!

Comment: It seems to work now :-D However, if some person is unavailable on all days except Monday and he/she has not got all those shifts he should, and the last day to place is Tuesday, the while loop will run forever. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Give me a few minutes will post a revision for you!

Comment: By the way i am about to add this into my restaurant management software just a much more complex version of it!

Comment: @Jamgreen  I have edited the code by adding a failSafe function. This function will be called if the random fails to find an employee after 15 attempts(or how ever many you set it to). This function filters through your array of employees to first find an employee that is both available and still has less than the number of shifts per employee. If this fails it re-runs the filter allowing for 1 more shift per person. If this fails then the function returns a false and the whole script fails